# Can I use a custom root domain for a bluemix CF application?

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

I want to use a bare domain with a bluemix CF app. (A bare domain is also known as a zone apex, usually the domain you bought with nothing on the front of it, e.g. "azquelt.co.uk")

The [bluemix docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#domain) for configuring a custom domain say you must configure a CNAME record for the hostname that you want to associate with a bluemix application.

However, you [cannot create a CNAME record for a bare domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) (e.g. something like "azquelt.co.uk"). This is a limitation of DNS.

Is it possible to use a bare domain name with a bluemix application or is this not supported?

Comment: You usually have some DNS management for your bare domain, so you can make use of it. Have you looked into what records you can define/manage for your domain?
I am using my own domain for some bluemix apps, e.g., "chat.azquelt.co.uk" would be one of the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a bare domain name in Bluemix. Basically you have to set the A record for your bare domain to point to the Bluemix domain IP address for your region. To find the IP address simply `ping` the hostname corresponding your region. For example for US South region you should user 75.126.81.68:

`$ ping secure.us-south.bluemix.net
PING secure.us-south.bluemix.net (75.126.81.68): 56 data bytes`

The link you mentioned has the hostnames for other Bluemix regions as well.

To configure your application:

1) Create a custom domain in Bluemix using your bare domain (for example azquelt.co.uk

2) In your Bluemix application add a new route and select this new custom domain for the route and leave the host field empty. In this case your application will be reachable in your bare domain.

Comment: If I do this, am I at risk of my app breaking if bluemix changes the IP address? Is this likely to happen?

Comment: Well I cannot guarantee that the IP address will never change, but I can tell you that this IP have not changed for a while (I believe it never changed) and until recently we published the IP directly instead of host name. If the IP changes your app will likely not be reached.

Comment: This article is pretty good - lists what you have to do on IBM Cloud (bluemix) as well as on your domain provider:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/apps/updapps.html#domain